# Fixed Sticky Navbar

Tags: css

How do i get a fixed navigation for my website? i want the menu on my site to remain stick to the page as the user scroll downs to see the content.

The navigation disappears as the user scroll down at the very bottom of the page. How do i make it stay? I tried using this but it doesn't work.

/* The sticky class is added to the navbar  */

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove

```
.nav-secondary {
   margin-top: -100px; 
   padding-top: 100px;
}
```

and replace with

```
.nav-secondary {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
#genesis-mobile-nav-secondary{top:0; position:sticky;}
```